# How to print 2D array simplest way with foreach loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, foreach, 2d

I was wondering what the simplest way of printing a 2D array?
I know we can print 1D array just like this code below.

```
int[ ] numbers = {2, 3, 5, 7};    
for (int print: numbers) {
   System.out.println(print); 
}
```

I tried to print the code below of course it didn't work.

```
int[ ][ ] numbers= { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} }; 
for (int print: numbers) {
       System.out.println(print); 
    }
```

I know I can print with nested loops like the code below but I was wondering if I can use foreach loop just like 1D array. Thank you

```
 int[ ][ ] numbers= { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} }; 
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(numbers[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2-dimensional array each element in first loop will be an 1-dimensional array, in second loop each element is a number itself:

```
int[][] array2d = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
for (int[] array : array2d) {
    for (int element : array) {
        System.out.print(element + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Actually, there is a better way using `Arrays::toString` library method:

```
int[][] numbers = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
for (int[] array : numbers) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @J-Alex! It is what I have been trying to do last 45 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

print 2D array simplest way with foreach loop :

**Exmple :**

```
 public class Print2DArr {


            public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                         int[ ][ ] numbers= { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} }; 
                              for (int[] arr:  numbers) {
                              for (int num :  arr ) {
                              System.out.print(num +  " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
             }

          }
```

Output :

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

However, the libs do supply the method `deepToString` for this purpose, so this may also suit your purposes:

```
public class Print2DArr {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 int[ ][ ] numbers= { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} }; 
                   System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(numbers));

}
```

Output :

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Try my second purposes!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stream.of()` for that too:

```
Stream.of(new int[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}).forEach(x -> {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
    });
Output: [1, 2, 3]
        [4, 5, 6]
        [7, 8, 9]
```

But `Arrays.deepToString()` is a better way I think.

```
System.out.println(
        Arrays.deepToString(
            new int[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
        ));
Output: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to use a foreach loop to print a 2D array:

```
public class MyClass
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] myNumbers = { {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7} };

        // To access the elements of the myNumbers array,
        // specify two indexes: one for the array, and one
        // for the elements inside that array.

        for(int i : myNumbers[0]) // Here accessing the first array with index 0:
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        for(int j : myNumbers[1]) // Here accessing the second array with index 1:
        {
            System.out.println(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

Comment: Compared to the other answers here, yours requires knowing ahead of time that you'll have exactly two arrays nested within `myNumbers`. If you were to add another one, it won't get printed, and if you removed one (or both) of the nested arrays, the code would crash.